# Cannot map an array of data from firebase database

Tags: firebase, react-native, web, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-cli

I am making a blood bank app and i am experiencing a problem in which I can't map my list of data in react native JSX. I copied most of the code from my [todoApp](https://github.com/shaheerkhandev/TodoApp) that I made in react native earlier and modified it. I also want it to get all the data automatically when a user opens the app instead of manually using a button.

**APP.JS:**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {Button,Text, View, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
    import firebase from 'firebase';
    
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBPAEj0ku0YBF1DzCc1b6mGpEKz0Bhn9Fk",
  authDomain: "bloodbank-pro.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "bloodbank-pro",
  storageBucket: "bloodbank-pro.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "533183192799",
  appId: "1:533183192799:web:82b1a608af84d64e6d536a",
  measurementId: "G-06F49XSLF4"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    export default class App extends React.Component {
    
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                list: [],
            }
        }
          
        work=()=>{
            firebase.database().ref().once('value').then(snapshot => {
             var snap = snapshot.val();
             var newStateArray = this.state.list.slice();
             newStateArray.push({id: this.state.list.length + 1,username: snap.username, age: snap.age, bloodtype: snap.bloodtype, phonenumber: snap.phonenumber});
             this.setState({list: newStateArray,});
            });
        }  
    
        render(){
            return(<>
            <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', marginVertical:20 }} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}>
            <View>
              {this.state.list.map(item => (<>
                <View key={item.id}  style={{borderBottomColor: 'black',borderBottomWidth: 5, marginBottom: 20}}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 22}}>{item.username}, {item.age}, {item.phonenumber}, {item.bloodtype}</Text>
                </View>
              </>))}
            </View>
            </ScrollView>
                <View style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 1, left: 1, right: 1,}}>
                <Button title="test" onPress={this.work} />
                <Button title="Go to My Profile" />
                </View>
                </>)
        }
    }
```

**FIREBASE DB:**
[image: My Firebase database]

This is made in react native CLI. I will be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you app is trying to fetch the data before the database is totally initialized. The best pratice is putting the

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBPAEj0ku0YBF1DzCc1b6mGpEKz0Bhn9Fk",
  authDomain: "bloodbank-pro.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "bloodbank-pro",
  storageBucket: "bloodbank-pro.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "533183192799",
  appId: "1:533183192799:web:82b1a608af84d64e6d536a",
  measurementId: "G-06F49XSLF4"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

In the `index.js`of your project. In your `index.js` file put write

```
componentDidMount() {
  const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBPAEj0ku0YBF1DzCc1b6mGpEKz0Bhn9Fk",
  authDomain: "bloodbank-pro.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "bloodbank-pro",
  storageBucket: "bloodbank-pro.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "533183192799",
  appId: "1:533183192799:web:82b1a608af84d64e6d536a",
  measurementId: "G-06F49XSLF4"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

In the `App.js` file write:

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.work()
}
```

Comment: i also had to change my firebase function to firebase.database().ref().on('child_added', (childSnapshot) from firebase.database().ref().once('value')